# ReactJS: When to run analytics Page Load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I'm using React with React-Router.

I need to add a google analytics event on page load, but I need to run when the page finish render. It means, after all the renders it does after the page is usable.

Is there a way to recognize from react when the page finish it loads?
I know I can use some native methods, but maybe there is something out there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the lifecycle methods

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Hmm but it will run each time, I need to run just in last render